# Enviar datos a mi bd laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Tengo una tabla que le hago varias inserciones por js, pero ahora nose como capturar todos esos datos y enviarlos a mi bd, alguien me pod6ria orientar por favor, soy nuevo en este tema, adjunto imagen y código

Los datos que están en la tabla a continuación son los que debo enviar a mi BD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CÓDIGO JQUERY

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_button').click(function(){
      // capturo los datos guardado en los inputs
      
      var clase = document.getElementById("clase").value;
      var fecha_clase = document.getElementById("fecha_clase").value;
      var hora_clase = document.getElementById("hora_clase_input").value;
      var duracion_clase = document.getElementById("duracion_clase").value;
      var profesor = document.getElementById("profesor").value;
      var i = 1; //contador para asignar id al boton de borrar fila
      var fila = '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>'+ clase + '</td><td>'+ fecha_clase + '</td><td>' + hora_clase + '</td><td>' + duracion_clase + '</td><td>' + profesor + '</td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Quitar</button></td></tr>';
      var contador = i++;
      i++;

      $('#tablaAgregados tr:first').after(fila);
      $("#adicionados").text("");


      var nFilas = $("#tablaAgregados tr").length;

      $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);//restador de filas, se coloco -1 para uqe nose elimine el header
      
      // limpiamos los inputs
      document.getElementById("clase").value ="clase "+nFilas+"";
      document.getElementById("fecha_clase").value ="";
      document.getElementById("hora_clase").value = "";
      document.getElementById("duracion_clase").value = "";
      document.getElementById("profesor").value = "";
     });
      // eliminacion de fila
      $(document).on('click','.btn_remove',function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
          $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
          $("#adicionados").text("");
          var nFilas = $("tablaAgregados tr").length;
          $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
      });


    
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Utilizas jquery para capturar los datos y mostrarlos en la tabla por algún motivo en especial?. Porque se podría enviar cada registro a tu BD y mostrarlo en la tabla con ajax. Es decir, insertas un registro, al pulsar el botón añadir se envía directamente a la BD a través de ajax y se muestra en la tabla, todo de una sola vez.

Comment: Investiga sobre `ajax`, o `fetch` de javascript, se que lo lograras

Comment: @belkin220 igual lo pense de esa manera, peor al momento en que el usuario registre 20 clases, tendira uqe ir borrando una por una si es que necesita eliminar todas, y esto me resulto mas practico para el proyecto que desarrollo, lo otro es que no sabia que al momento de abrir el modal, no me muestre las clases anteriormente registradas y solo me muestre las que este ingresando actualmente (nose si se entiende)

Comment: @Shassain me recomendaron esas 2 opciones tengo que investigar

Comment: gracias por tu apoyo y a los dos por responder